# Creating New Rows based On the Count of New Rows in R

Tags: r, subset

Hi I am new to R and my data looks like this

```
row name units.1  units.2   units.3
       1        1       0        0
       2        0       1        0
       3        2       0        1
       4        0       0        0
```

I want to add a new row containing the count of other rows that are greater than 1, like this:

```
row name units.1  units.2   units.3
   1        1       0        0
   2        0       1        0
   3        2       0        1
   4        0       0        0
   5        2       1        1
```

so I can subset that later. Thanks in advance

I also want to subset the data based on the sum of row 5, for example I want only those column whose value in row 5 is 2 or more.

```
   row name units.1  
       1        1       
       2        0      
       3        2      
       4        0       
       5        2
```

Note my data has around 5K columns so I can't do this manually. Thanks again

Comment: `colSums(mydf > 0)` should be enough to give you the information you need. You should drop the first value though, since that's not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df <- rbind(df, colSums(df > 1))
```

Assuming your data is called "df". This would create a new row with the information in your data set. However, if you only need this to subset your data later, you might not need to actually include this row in your data. Instead, you could just calculate the same values during the subsetting.

#### Edit after question update:

Option 1:

If you want to select all those columns of df, where the number of entries > 1 are more than 2 in the column, you could do it like this without first creating the extra row:

```
df[, c(TRUE, colSums(df[,-1]) > 2)]
#  row.name units.1
#1        1       1
#2        2       0
#3        3       2
#4        4       0
```

To understand this, you need to look at

```
c(TRUE, colSums(df[,-1]) > 2)
#        units.1 units.2 units.3 
#   TRUE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
```

So this creates a logical vector, where the first element is TRUE (that is for the "row name" column because you want to keep it) and then for the other columns, it is TRUE if the column has more than 2 entries greater than 1.

Option 2:

If you want to use the extra row that you created, you can do for example:

```
df[, c(TRUE, df[nrow(df),] > 2)]
#  row.name units.1
#1        1       1
#2        2       0
#3        3       2
#4        4       0
#5        5       2
```

The approach is similar, but you only the if the entries in the last row (therefore the `nrow(df)` of each column are > 2.

Comment: +1 But, I am guessing the `row name` is the first column here. `rbind(df, c(row.name=5,colSums(df[,-1]>0)))`

Comment: @akrun, yes good point in case that is really a column in the data. I would slightly change it to `rbind(df, c(nrow(df)+1 ,colSums(df[,-1]>0)))` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still need to subset the data based on the new row. Can you help me with this one. Thank you

Comment: @JohnBrianL.Estares, sure I can help you if you let me and everyone else know how exactly you want to perform the subset or, more precisely, what your expected result is. Please edit your question with that information and I'll try to update my answer.